# Why do many plasmids for Flp-mediated Flip-Excision only flanked by one FRT site on each side and not two non-homologous?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, recombination

I'm trying to build some molecular gene switches into a model, and want to use both Cre and Flp. I understand how to invert gene segments with Cre, double floxing (e.g. with loxP and lox2272, like [in this plasmid for example](https://www.addgene.org/73476/)). To do the same with Flp/frt, I was looking at Plasmid constructs on Addgene, but [most results](https://www.addgene.org/search/catalog/plasmids/?q=Flp%20frt%20flex) are only flanked by one (inverted) FRT site on each side. From my understanding, this would lead to flip-flopping back and forth, so when FLP is not expressed anymore, you'd get a 50/50 distribution.
Can somebody explain to me why they do not use two frt sites, but instead one?
Thank you very much!